# Hide or show external frames

Tags: java

Is there a way I can hide a window or frame in another program? For example, if you had a Firefox window open and you ran your program, it would do the same as saying firefoxFrame.setVisible(false) but obviously, I don't have that reference to another program's frame. Then maybe later, firefoxFrame.setVisible(true)

Answer (score 1):

As my dad always says -- use the right tool for the job. For this job, where you need to get close to the OS, to find out your window handles and make OS calls to make them invisible, Java simply isn't the right tool. Java was built to be as OS agnostic as possible to allow it to run on multiple platforms. While yes, you can do this with Java with JNA or JNI, it requires that you jump through hoops that aren't needed if you use a better tool such as a scripting language (think AutoIt for Windows) or C/C++.